# Program doesnt want to read file

Tags: c, file, struct

this is my struct

```
   typedef struct {
        char mmsi[10];
        char name[20];
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        int course;
        double speed;
    }Vessel;
```

this is my function which doesnt want to work

```
void searchByLatLong(double latitude, double longitude){
        FILE * file;
        struct dirent *drnt;
        DIR * dir = opendir("./text");
        char *path = (char *)malloc(19);
        Vessel *vessel = (Vessel *)malloc(sizeof(Vessel));

        while((drnt = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            if(strcmp(drnt->d_name,".") && strcmp(drnt->d_name,"..")) {

                strcpy(path,"text/");
                strcat(path,drnt->d_name);

                file=fopen(path, "r");
                fscanf(file," %s %[a-zA-Z0-9 ]19s %lf %lf %d %lf", &vessel->mmsi,&vessel->name,&vessel->latitude,&vessel->longitude,&vessel->course,&vessel->speed);

        //  if (mmsi+".txt" == drnt->d_name){
                    printf("%s\n%s\n%lf\n%lf\n%d\n%lf\n\n",vessel->mmsi,vessel->name,vessel->latitude,vessel->longitude,vessel->course,vessel->speed);
            //}


            fclose(file);
        }
        seekdir(dir, telldir(dir)); 

    //  if(this->mmsi == mmsi){
        //  printVessel();
    //  }

    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

When i try to load txt file it loads only two first strings then after it theres some rubbish from memory. Loading the data to another variables changes nothing ;/ 
This is a sample txt file which should be loaded:

```
3
RMS Titanic
22.222
33.333
4
5.9
```

Comment: In any case you should add some error checking to your code. `fscanf` returns a pretty useful value ― the number of items that have been successfully read. That could help in finding the real cause. (The same goes for `fopen`, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your format string.  The correct format string is:

```
" %s %19[a-zA-Z0-9 ] %lf %lf %d %lf"
```

The field width goes before the conversion specifier.  Also, the [...] sequence is a conversion specifier, just like 's'.  The problem you're seeing is that `fscanf()` processes the '3' because it matches the first `%s`.  Then it processes the 'RMS Titanic' because it matches `%[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` but then processing stops because there is no '19s' in the input.  At this point the remaining arguments are uninitialized.

You should check the return value from `fscanf()`.  It will tell you how many conversions were actually performed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting an interesting question; I learned about `fscanf()` and the `[]` notation it accepts.

The `[]` notation specifies that a string is being read, therefore, the `s` you have appended to it is considered a literal character that should match.  Similarly, the width-specifier you have provided, `19` should appear prior to the `[]`.

Your current code would start working if you had a ship named, e.g., "RMS Titanic19s".

Change your fscanf to:

```
fscanf(file," %s %19[a-zA-Z0-9 ] %lf %lf %d %lf",
    vessel->mmsi,vessel->name,&vessel->latitude,
    &vessel->longitude,&vessel->course,&vessel->speed);
```

and your code will start working.

Notice I fixed some compile warnings by dropping the superfluous `&` from the `char []` members `mmsi` and `name` -- these already point to the buffers you wish to fill.  You don't need `&` in front of them.  A pedagogical alternative form is `&vessel->mmsi[0]` -- the address of the first character of `mmsi`.